# php - Using type hinting and dependency injection

Tags: php, testing, object, types

I'm using [Type Hinting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php) on a class that gets passed an object into its constructor. The passed object (Bar) exists in its own namespace. This is all fine until I swap out the passed object with a fake one (for unit testing purposes). My test Bar object resides in its own namespace and now an error is (quite rightly) thrown.

```
use Some\Place\Bar
class Foo {
    // Passing a test Bar into here now throws error.
    public function __construct(Bar $bar) {
        $this->bar = $bar;
    }

}
```

I'm new to PHP so unsure on what is possible. Is there a way round this or do I just need to drop Type Hinting from the class (which is my current solution)?

Comment: Yes I did, thanks for the correction. Edited

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2 of the several options :

pass an object in the constructor that implement an interface IBar :

```
 interface IBar{
  function baz();
 }

 class Bar implements IBar{
    function baz(){ return $this->getSomethingExpensiveFromDatabase();}
 }

 class FakeBar implements IBar{
    function baz(){ return "baz";}
 }

 class Foo {
 function __construct(IBar $bar) ...
```

or dont use type hinting

```
function __construct($bar)
```

the point is , the signature of a method should never depend on an implementation , always an interface.

EDIT : so you just need to import the interface then the fake class wherever it comes from. FakeBar can then mock Bar.

Comment: After more learning I can see how this answer makes more sense to my situation. Updated my accept. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Type juggling is an entirely different thing, what you are showing here is [type hinting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php). You cannot pass in an object that has the same class name, but resides in a different namespace, but you can pass in an object from a class, that inherits from the class that your method expects:

```
namespace Testing;
use Some\Place\Bar;
class TestingBar extends Bar {
}
```

You can then pass an instance of TestingBar to your method.

If you want to use the same name for both the original Bar class, and the testing Bar class, you will need to alias one of them out (I would advise against it though):

```
namespace Testing;
use Some\Place\Bar as OriginalBar;

class Bar extends OriginalBar {
}
```

Comment: Extending the original class with a test version and overriding the method with an appropriate fake seems to work perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: while it is some kind of Pythonic trick and it maybe correct, it defeats the purpose of type hinting --imho-- since anything can have the right class name

Comment: Both answers seem good to me. Had to pick one. Upvoted yours too. If there is a concrete reason to pick one over the other I'll re-accept. Thanks